# 5-star rating doesn't inform UITableView of updated value; custom UIView class works

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview

So I did [the Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1768/uiview-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-make-a-custom-uiview-in-ios-5-a-5-star-rating-view) tutorial for a 5-star review view, only I modified it to do half-star ratings.

It looked like it was working perfectly, but it turns out, the custom UIView is not always updating the UITableView that the rating value changed.

I added a NSLog() to display the rating value in the custom class, and then added a label to output the value in the TableView. It seems like, it takes a very deliberate tap-drag-stop-lift finger action to get it to update the TableView value.  Any thoughts?? Following is some code snipets:

Modified 'Handle Touch'

```
 (void)handleTouchAtLocation:(CGPoint)touchLocation {
    if (!self.editable) return;


    float newRating = 0;

    for(int i = self.imageViews.count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        UIImageView *imageView = [self.imageViews objectAtIndex:i];        
        CGFloat distance = touchLocation.x - imageView.frame.origin.x;

        if (distance <= 0) continue;
        if (distance < imageView.frame.size.width / 2) {
            newRating = i + 0.5;
            break;
        } else if (distance > imageView.frame.size.width / 2){
            newRating = i + 1;
            break;
        }

    }

    self.rating = newRating;
    NSLog(@"Self.rating = %f", self.rating);
}
```

Segments of my tableView .h/.m file

My .h

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet RateView *queenRateView;
```

My .m

```
   //Queen Performance Rating
    self.queenRateView.rating = 0;
    self.queenRateView.editable = YES;
    self.queenRateView.maxRating = 5;
    self.queenRateView.delegate = self;

- (void)rateView:(RateView *)rateView ratingDidChange:(float)rating {
    NSLog(@"Queen Rating from Class: %f", rating);

    queenRating = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: rating];
    NSLog(@"Queen Rating: %@", queenRating);
    self.queenRatingLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", queenRating];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you messing this part :

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  [self.delegate rateView:self ratingDidChange:self.rating];
  }